# automatically copy rows that contain text in a specific column when pasting to another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a macro to copy data from a form, then open a separate workbook and paste the data into the next empty row. The user has 21 rows of information they can fill out, but the number of rows actually filled out will vary from day to day.

The following code works with the exception that, when pasted into the destination workbook, the blank cells are treated as if they contain data. So I end up with several blank rows in between each data dump.

How can I alter this code to copy all rows in the range of row 5 - row 25 that contain text in column "I" but ignore any rows that are blank in column "I"?

```
Sub Export_Data()
Dim owb As Workbook
Dim sh As Worksheet

Set sh = Sheet1
sh.Range("A5:K25").Copy
Set owb = Workbooks.Open("my_destination_workbook")

owb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
owb.Close True
End Sub
```

Comment: Are all the completed rows sequential, e.g. 5-10 ?

Answer (score 0):

I took a For Loop approach to look at values in Column A and skip empty ones. There are many ways to go about this, this is just one.

```
Sub Export_Data()
    Dim owb As Workbook
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim sRange as Range
    Dim i as Long

    Set sh = Sheet1
    Set owb = Workbooks.Open("my_destination_workbook")

    For i = 5 to 25 Step + 1 'from 5 to 25 because you are checking A5:K25
        'If "A & i" has a value, copy A to Z and paste it at the end on the new workbook
        If sh.Range("A" & i).Value <> 0 Then
            sh.Range("A" & i & ":K" & i).Copy
            owb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
    Next
    owb.Close True
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks Ricardo A

Your code worked to loop through everything, but unfortunately it was still picking up the blank rows. I made a slight alteration and changed

```
If sh.Range("A" & i).Value <> 0 Then
```

to

```
If sh.Range("A" & i).Value <> "" Then
```

And now it only copies the rows that have a value entered into column I.
So the following code now works to copy all rows with a value in column I, and then open a new workbook and paste the copied rows into the next empty row.

```
Sub Export_Data()
Dim owb As Workbook
Dim sh As Worksheet

Set sh = Sheet1
Set owb = Workbooks.Open("my_destination_workbook")

For i = 5 To 25 Step 1
    If sh.Range("A" & i).Value <> "" Then
        sh.Range("A" & i & ":K" & i).Copy
        owb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End If
Next

owb.Close True
```

End Sub